# scikits.statsmodels can not be installed with pip python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, scikits

The official documentation https://scikits.appspot.com/statsmodels says that "scikits.statsmodels has been ported and tested for Python 3.2." but I get:

```
$ pip install scikits.statsmodels
Collecting scikits.statsmodels
   Using cached scikits.statsmodels-0.3.1.tar.gz
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-dbu7u2oo/scikits.statsmodels/setup.py", line 96
        print "debug import success GIT_REVISION", GIT_REVISION
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-dbu7u2oo/scikits.statsmodels/
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I just copy it here : https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3598

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.statsmodels/0.3.1) for scikits.statsmodels says:

> The name of scikits.statsmodels has been changed to statsmodels, the new version is at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels

So try

```
pip install statsmodels
```

FWIW I use statsmodels regularly in 3.6, so I'm pretty optimistic it'll work. :-)